# Working on Kafka load testing with jmeter and getting unable to connect kafka and timeout issues

Tags: java, performance, apache-kafka, jmeter

Created basic script for kafka with javarequest and JSR223 sampler. During script execution getting below error .

Sample script :

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeader;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeaders;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("zookeeper.connect", "Zookeper:2181");
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "b-1..amazonaws.com:9096");
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("compression.type", "none");
props.put("batch.size", "16384");
props.put("linger.ms", "0");
props.put("buffer.memory", "33554432");
props.put("acks", "1");
props.put("send.buffer.bytes", "131072");
props.put("receive.buffer.bytes", "32768");
props.put("security.protocol", "SASL SSL");
props.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");
props.put("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512");

//System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","C:/kafka/JAAS.conf");

props.put("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:/kafka/JAAS.conf");

KafkaProducer\<String, String\> producer = new KafkaProducer\<String, String\>(props);
```

Errors:

```
\[1:38 PM\] veerajah, neelam (contracted)

2022-12-26 08:07:47,302 INFO o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer: \[Producer clientId=JMeterKafkaBackendListener\] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.

\[1:39 PM\] veerajah, neelam (contracted)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer

\[1:40 PM\] veerajah, neelam (contracted)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `b-1..amazonaws.com:9096` host and port combination is reachable from JMeter load generator(s)

1. Kafka broker is running
2. Port 9096 is open in operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
3. Port 9096 is open in [AWS security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)
4. If any VPN or proxy is needed to reach the Kafka broker - make sure to connect to the VPN or [make JMeter aware of the proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

More information: [How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get AWS JKS file will get downloaded from KAFKA.

Comment: @Neelam MSK support should be able to get you that